# Error in adding indexing to json file for fetching data from firebase.Invalid JSON. Keys cannot be empty or contain $ # [ ] / or

Tags: json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, postman

I am trying to fetch data from firebase using postman on the basis of some condition like if the score is greater than 50. For which I was supposed to add indexing in my JSON file on the basis of documentation link :
https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/indexing-data.html

So the code which I have written on the basis of documentation is :

```
{
    "rules": {
        "scores": {
            ".indexOn": ".value"
        }
    },
    "scores": {
        "bruhathkayosaurus" : 55,
        "lambeosaurus" : 21,
        "linhenykus" : 80,
        "pterodactyl" : 93,
        "stegosaurus" : 5,
        "triceratops" : 22
    }
}
```

But when i am uploading this json to firebase i am getting error :

Invalid JSON. Keys cannot be empty or contain $ # [ ] / or .

I don't know what I have written wrong. Are the rules supposed to be written at some other place or in some other format? I am a beginner so do not have much knowledge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rules are supposed to be written in firebase only and not in the json file which we upload. The rules are to be written as per documentation and your requirement (what you want to fetch) but in the area shown in image(in the red circle) :

[image]

`Select Database -> Realtime Database -> Rules`

In the screenshot I have included rules for fetching data on the basis of values of scores.

Answer (score 0):

Based on firabase docs, you have to either use their console or CLI (installed from NPM) to edit indexes.

[This link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/indexing) provides more details.

Comment: No it`s also not working. Postman generating error : "Index not defined, add \".indexOn\": \".value\", for path \"/address\", to the rules" . I think it is looking for .indexOn in "rules" as suggested in documentation but it is not available in the automatic generated file through CLI .

Comment: You are not supposed to use postman for index editing, The docs specifically explain how to use CLI (yes you need to edit the generated JSON file and add indexes you need): https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/indexing#use_the_firebase_cli

Comment: I used CLI for generating indexes and edited and than again uploaded it. I am just trying to make a GET request using POSTMAN which is generating the above error.